# How do you access a var from inside another javascript file's function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, scope, global-variables

I've seen similar questions on stack but I wasn't able to implement a solution for my usecase.

For some context, I'm trying to store the latitude/longitude variables in an array called cords (Script.js):

```
function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var cords = [{lat : latitude, long : longitude}];
   
    console.log(cords);

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;

  }
  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }
  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    //navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error);
  }
}

document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
```

I'm trying to access this variable and save it to a local text file (Script2.js):

```
function saveStaticDataToFile() {
    console.log("Clicked")
    
    var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.download = "cords.txt";
    a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(JSON.stringify(cords));
    a.innerHTML = "Save Cords";
  
}
  
document.querySelector('#filesaver').addEventListener('click', saveStaticDataToFile);
```

This is the method I got to work to save the file locally, but I was hoping someone could help me with how to do this/best practices?

I've tried some things like initializing cords outside the function and some bad attempt at aysnc-await.

If you want to try running it:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
    <p id = "status"></p>
    <a id = "map-link" target="_blank"></a>
    
    <button id="filesaver">Click to Save</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `cords` outside the function scope to be available for both functions. The solution is to design your application in a way that you don't try to save the `cords` before even getting it from the browser. Add some error/info before the user gets the location from the browser.

```js
var cords = null;

function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    cords = [{lat : latitude, long : longitude}];
   
    console.log(cords);

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;

  }
  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }
  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    //navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error);
  }
}

document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);

function saveStaticDataToFile() {
    console.log("Clicked")
    
    // Show an error/info here to the user
    if (!cords) console.log('Please get the location first');
    
    var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.download = "cords.txt";
    a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(JSON.stringify(cords));
    a.innerHTML = "Save Cords";
  
}
  
document.querySelector('#filesaver').addEventListener('click', saveStaticDataToFile);
```

```html
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
    <p id = "status"></p>
    <a id = "map-link" target="_blank"></a>
    
    <button id="filesaver">Click to Save</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The scripts in html file work as one script you can declare a variable in global scope and access it from anywhere you want in the different scripts you have on the html

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Location</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="find-me">Show my location</button><br />
    <p id="status"></p>
    <a id="map-link" target="_blank"></a>
    <br>
    <!-- i used a link directly here so you dont have to click twice to download the file -->
    <a id="filesaver" href="">Click to Save</a>

    <!-- this script works like the same script even they are from different files/scripts -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
// getting element from dom
// global scope constants
const FILE_SAVER = document.querySelector('#filesaver');
const STATUS = document.querySelector('#status');
const MAP_LINK = document.querySelector('#map-link');

let cords = []; // global scope variable so you can access it from the scripts below this one

FILE_SAVER.style.display = 'none'; // hiding the 'save file button' until we get the coords

const success = (position) => {
    const { coords: { latitude, longitude } } = position; // using ES6 syntax to make the code easy to read
    STATUS.textContent = '';
    MAP_LINK.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    MAP_LINK.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude}°, Longitude: ${longitude}°`;
    cords = [{ lat: latitude, long: longitude }]; // setting the cords in the global cords variable
    FILE_SAVER.style.display = 'block'  // displaying the 'save file button'
}
const error = () => {
    STATUS.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
}

const geoFindMe = () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        STATUS.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
    } else {
        STATUS.textContent = 'Locating...';
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
}
document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
```

script2.js:

```
const saveStaticDataToFile = () => {
    // using FILE_SAVER constant from the first script `we can access it from here bc we declare in global scope`
    FILE_SAVER.download = "cords.txt";
    FILE_SAVER.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(JSON.stringify(cords));
}

document.querySelector('#filesaver').addEventListener('click', saveStaticDataToFile);
```